# C# Programmatically send two keys when you are already pressing another one

Tags: c#

I'm making my own multiple clipboard copy/paste tool which runs in background, and I've finally achieved it, it's working.

this is how it works,

- when Capslock it's pressed, if I press CTRL+1 I make a CTRL+C programmatically ( with SendKeys) and save the clipboard on my list with correct position
- when capslock it's not pressed, if I press CTRL+1 I make a CTRL+V programmatically ( with send keys) by using the latest data in clipboard on the correct list position.

Now it's fine, but I want to make a little change, I don't want to use capslock, but I want to press another key, like ALT or SHIFT, but if you keep pressing a key which is not the CTRL and then you do a CTRL+C, it does not work.

Anyone have any advice to this dumb thing?

Thanks guy

Comment: I've tried with CTRL + SHIFT + C and it work fine ...

Comment: Note: Using `SendKeys` to simulate `CTRL+C` and `CTRL+V` is not a proper way to interact with the clipboard, and will result in poor behavior in many situations (i.e., situations where those shortcuts are not bound to copy and paste).  The correct way to interact with the clipboard is by using the appropriate API calls.

Comment: I agree with Brian, you shouldn't assume that CTRL+C and CTRL+V copy/paste, you should assume that windows functions work properly though. Neat idea btw, that actually seems kinda useful :)

Comment: I was using a HookManager for capturing the outside form mouse and keyboard clicks, which currenctly works really great.

Comment: ok, Now I'm using SendInput win api.. it's definitely better but it does not solve my problem :( is there no way to call a "COPY" win api without using keys?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using WinApi functions, you can use **RegisterHotKey** and **UnregisterHotKey** functions. 
They allow you to register and unregister global shortcuts of your choice. This way you'll get notified about a shortcut being pressed even if your application is running in background and doesn't have the focus on itself.

You can find more information about both functions on **pinvoke** [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterHotKey.html) and [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/UnregisterHotKey.html). There is even some sample application code so you can see how to use them.

**NOTE:** Remember to unregister all the shortcuts that you've registered on application exit.

Comment: Excuse me, but this is used for CATCHING shortcuts, not sending shortucts, I'm correct?

Comment: Yes you are right. I thought that if you capture the shortcuts this way, you'll have no problem with sending the Ctrl+v. I've just tested this for Ctrl+Shift+W keys combination, used SendWait("^V") in handling code and it worked correctly.

Comment: One thing to consider is to make sure that an active application doesn't define a behaviour for some of the keys itself i.e. on pressing Alt a menu can pop up, which takes focus away from textbox and make it unable to complete the paste operation, which looks like it doesn't work. It can be similar in case of copying text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag for the select key.  When you check to see what keys are pressed then:

something like the following pseudo code should do the trick:

```
if(select key)
{
  this.selectKey = true;
}
else
{
  if(ctrl key)
    {
        //do whatever you would normally do here
    }
   this.selectKey = false;
}
```